# What's the windows version of this node command?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, command

**My problem:**
I saw a react project in github and I want to run it on my Windows computer. This project contains two part: client part and server part. I have no problem running the clinet but I can't run the server. I think the problem is that the author of this project developed it in Mac OS so he used the mac version of the node command. Here is the command I have trouble running:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=src ts-node-dev --respawn --ignore-watch node_modules --no-notify src"
  },
```

**What I tried:**
To verify my assumption, I tried to run the same server on a Macbook by running 'npm run watch' and it works. So I guess I need to change the watch command into corresponding windows command, right? If so, what should I change it to?

Comment: What is the output error when you run on Windows?

Comment: Same command should work on Windows.. You need to make sure you have [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) installed, though. `npm i -g ts-node-dev`